# Make a method able to do something when an exception is thrown

Tags: java

I'm doing a little program and 
I would like a method to show an error message when a null argument is passed, without doing its work.
I thinked

```
public void doSomething (String) {
try
{
   //other
} catch (Exception IllegalArgumentException){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Null argument passed");
}
}
```

But it does not work. 
Any idea?

---

**UPDATE**

Seen the banner of off-topic, I try to be more precise. I have a method that has to write in Database what it's passed like argument.
Naturally there is the "risk" that an unconscious user pass a null string and obviously I don't want my DB written by null strings.
So I'd like to resolve this simple problem.
Here my code

```
public void insertTeach(String teachName, int studentsNum) { 
try {
    String query1 = "INSERT INTO teaching (Name, StudentsNum)"
            + "VALUES ('" + teachName+ "','"
            + StudentsNum + "');";
    PreparedStatement statement=con.prepareStatement(query1);
    statement.executeUpdate();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data successfully inserted");
}

catch (Exception ex){
    System.out.println("Errore: "+ex);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error in writing. Try Again.");
}
```

If I write the if statetement in the body of try, if statement is completely ignored.

```
public void insertTeach(String teachName, int studentsNum) { 
try {
           if (param == null) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Null argument passed");
           return;
           }

    String query1 = "INSERT INTO teaching (Name, StudentsNum)"
            + "VALUES ('" + teachName+ "','"
            + StudentsNum + "');";
    PreparedStatement statement=con.prepareStatement(query1);
    statement.executeUpdate();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data successfully inserted");
}

catch (Exception ex){
    System.out.println("Errore: "+ex);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error in writing. Try Again.");
}
```

What I have to do?

Comment: What do you mean by *it does not work*? Didn't give you the expected results, never executed?

Comment: @Luigi, the system does not recognize the exception and do what it has to do (in this case write DB) with null String

Comment: Do you really have a variable named IllegalArgumentException of type Exception in your catch block, or is there a typo in your question?

Comment: The second statement: I have written a typo question

Comment: I'm surprised your if-statement doesn't give you compile errors, since I don't see any declaration of `param`.
Also, is your input string actually `null` at times, or is it an empty string? Because `"" != null`, so if your string is empty (but NOT NULL), the code will skip the if-statement.

Comment: The string is empty. I resolved with the statement `if (param.isEmpty()){..}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is actually catch a `NullPointerException` instead of a `IllegalArgumentException`. This is because an `IllegalArgumentException` is not thrown when someone passes a `null` as an argument, because `null` is not an illegal argument. So your code should look like -

```
public void doSomething (String) {
try
{
   //other
} catch (NullPointerException e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Null argument passed");
}
}
```

or better yet

```
public void doSomething (String) {
    if(String == null)//do error stuff
}
```

Comment: mmm with the if way it seems not very elegant.. isn't it?

Comment: @Bernheart, no it's not very elegant compared to what some other languages might offer, but it's pretty much the de facto way input data validation with Java is done. It gets really messy when you have multiple arguments to validate, and I can see your goal on making it cleaner. Maybe a custom validation class with its own set of ValidationExceptions is what you need. This is pretty much only speculations, though.

Comment: @Bernheart I think its just fine. What is not elegant about it? You have one specific case you want to check for and you have one simple boolean check (which is very efficient, its basically an integer comparison). Whats not to love?

Comment: @Dgrin91 I would like make it with exceptions' way (since Java offers me that instrument). But, as you and J ANDY tell me, that is the best and most efficient way to do my comparison.
By the way I thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
public void doSomething (String s) {
    if (s == null) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Null argument passed");
        return;
    }
    // actual work
}
```

Comment: Although your code is probably exactly what the OP needs, showing a piece of code doesn't really help him. It doesn't answer the question in any way, it doesn't tell why use this approach over the other, it doesn't tell why catching RuntimeExceptions is a bad practice, etc

Comment: @JAndy: Everything you're saying is right. However, I'm trying not to answer questions that were never asked. If an approach validation or some advice were requested, I would have probably suggested Guava `Preconditions` and handling exceptions in some other layer. But nobody asked for anything like that.

Comment: that's very true. Upvote for the the Preconditions, new for me too.